# Can we make the iPhone vibrate like Datepicker scrolls？

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

When you use Datepicker, whenever you scroll with date, iPhone will vibrate very lightly. I know we can 
 use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);` to make normal vibration. But can we make vibration like Datepicker?

Comment: I've never had an iPhone vibrate while scrolling a date picker. It clicks but it doesn't vibrate. Is there some accessibility setting for this?

Comment: I think it is a default setting? Very lightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `UIFeedbackGenerator` API. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
    generator.selectionChanged()
}
```